# How to detect single tap and double tap in android tablet using javascript

Tags: javascript

When clicking a particular element, i want to detect single tap and double tap using javascript in android tablet. Please suggest me any code.

I have tried various methods using settimeout, cleartimeout and preventDefault, but it won't works for me.

```
 if(isTouchDevice()){
   var end = new Date();
   if(this._doubleTapTimer != null && end - this._doubleTapTimer < 300){
         //DoubleClick event
         if (this.timer != null || this.timer != undefined) {
                   clearTimeout(this.timer);
                   this.timer == null;
          }
          alert('double tap');
   } 
   else {
          this.timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
             alert('single tap');
        }, 301);
   }
   this._doubleTapTimer = end; 
}
```

These code snippet is working for android mobile, ipad and it is not working in android tablet.

When single tap is done, need to do some process and when double click done then need to do another process.

Comment: are you try [`Touch Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

Comment: yes i have binded touchstart and touchend as mousedown and mouseup, after touchend, can't able to detect single and double tap.